# for/on 6 days in/throughout December - all possible?

Tags: prepositions

> 1. This event will be held **for 6 days in December.**
> 2. This event will be held **for 6 days throughout December.**
> 3. This event will be held **on 6 days in December.**
> 4. This event will be held **on 6 days throughout December.**

Comment: The version with "for six days throughout December" is deviant. "For six days" implies a (contiguous) time-span, and so it does not partner with "throughout".  We can find deciduous trees throughout a pine forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout December would mean during the whole of December

> Through or during the whole of (a period of time or course of action); from beginning to end of. *- OED*

You could conceivably use something like "throughout the first 6 days of December" but it sounds awkward to my ear.

That deals with your options 2 & 4, that leaves:

> 1 This event will be held for 6 days in December.
>
> 3 This event will be held on 6 days in December.

Both are grammatically correct but there is a subtle semantic difference. Generally, you would use *"for 6 days..."* for an event held over 6 consecutive days and *"on 6 days..."* if they are separate dates.